# Nifi won't start

Tags: apache-nifi

Can't get NiFi to even start, I think I've made a really obvious mistake, but there is no bin folder immedietly in the directory that I unzipped, which I downloaded from [here](https://nifi.apache.org/download.html)

The file structure in the folder that I have is like this:
[image: File structure]

Clearly have a bit of a stupid problem, appreciate the help.
There is a bin folder nested away in nifi-nar-bundles, but the .bat doesn't run.

Comment: you've downloaded sources instead of binaries )

Answer (score 5):

You need to download the binary zip or tar, not the source zip.

https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?path=/nifi/1.5.0/nifi-1.5.0-bin.tar.gz

or

https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?path=/nifi/1.5.0/nifi-1.5.0-bin.zip

Answer (score 1):

Bryan has provided the simplest solution. However, if you are interested in building it from source, you can use [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) to compile the source code you have downloaded into an executable application. The complete steps are [here](https://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html), but in summary:

1. Open a command prompt in this directory
2. Ensure Maven >= 3.1.0 and Java 8 are installed
3. Run the command `mvn clean install -T2.0C -DskipTests` (*clean* and *install* this application with *2 threads per core* and *skip running unit and integration tests*)
4. When the build is complete, change the directory to `nifi-assembly\target\nifi-1.5.0-bin\nifi-1.5.0\`
5. You will now see the `bin`, `conf`, `lib`, `logs`, etc. directories
6. Run `bin\nifi.bat start` to start NiFi